# WordPress Development - "Editor Style" issue

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm creating WordPress theme. But i faced with a interesting problem. So , I added a google font to Editor style. And It works correctly on localhost. Bu doesn't work on real host. Where can be problem ?
My Codes :

```
  # Editor Style support #
  add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
  # editor assets #
  add_editor_style(get_template_directory_uri() .'/style-editor.css');
  add_editor_style('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');
  add_editor_style('assets/css/font-awesome-4.css');
```

Comment: set `wp_debug` to true on the wp-config file then refresh the page the error will be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: Give this a try from the Wordpress Developer Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/

Using Google Fonts

Google Fonts API provides a single URL for a CSS file that can include multiple variants of a type face, separated by commas. Commas in a URL need to be encoded before the string can be passed to add_editor_style.

```
/**
 * Registers an editor stylesheet for the current theme.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    $font_url = str_replace( ',', '%2C', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' );
    add_editor_style( $font_url );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: Hello. I dont want to add fonts to site. It already works on blog. I want to add it to Visual Editor (admin editor). :)